# Title: How to virtualize MUI TreeView with over 1000 TreeItems to keep the DOM light?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, treeview, react-virtualized, react-window

I have a MUI TreeView component with over 1000 TreeItems and I'm noticing performance issues due to the large number of DOM elements being rendered. I've heard that virtualizing the TreeView can help keep the DOM light and improve performance, but I'm not sure how to do it.

What are some easy ways to virtualize the MUI TreeView to keep the DOM light when dealing with over 1000 TreeItems? Any code examples or resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

"I tried using the default implementation of MUI TreeView with over 1000 TreeItems and noticed significant performance issues due to the large number of DOM elements being rendered. I then researched how to virtualize the TreeView and came across several approaches, such as using the react-window package or implementing virtualization manually with the help of the MUI documentation.

My expectation was that virtualizing the TreeView would help improve performance by rendering only the visible nodes and reducing the number of DOM elements. I also expected to have a smoother user experience when scrolling or expanding/collapsing nodes in the TreeView."

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/petyosi/react-virtuoso or https://github.com/TanStack/virtual